# Dropdown Menus Disappear With Zero Margin

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, but I'm working on a Wordpress theme and I have the submenus styled exactly how I want them. However, they disappear upon hover. I have set all of my margin-tops to zero as stated on Stack previously but they still don't work properly.

My CSS for this top navigation is the following:

```
.top-nav {
background-color: #444;
min-height: 40px;
}

.top-nav ul {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.top-nav li {
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.top-nav li a {
color: #aaa;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.top-nav li a:hover, .top-nav li.current-menu-item a {
color: #fff; 
background-color: #444;
}

.top-nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
display: none; 
margin-top:0px;}

.top-nav ul li:hover > .sub-menu { 
display: block; 
position: absolute; 
height: 0px; 
margin-top:-5px; 
overflow: visible; 
margin-left:0px;}

.top-nav li.menu-item ul li { 
display: block; 
position:relative; 
width: 100%; 
float: left; 
margin:0px; 
padding:5px 0 5px 10px; 
background-color:#444!important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #faf3bf;}

.top-nav ul li.menu-item ul li a {
width: inherit; 
padding: 0;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove one `#` from `background-color: ##444;` in `.top-nav li a:hover, .top-nav li.current-menu-item a {`

Comment: Did you try it @Petey ???

Comment: Removed it from my code, but still having the same issue. Thanks for the heads up on that, though!

Comment: We really need to see this issue live. Could you make a JSfiddle example. You should add position values to the submenu though (`top:100%, left:0`) then you could probably lose the odd margins.

Comment: Paulie, here's the link to the site: http://tinyurl.com/ku6mlx7. Dropdowns can be seen under Artists.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/a4q5esc4/

Comment: Just posted the HTML output in JSFiddle.

Comment: post the HTML and javascript please.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add:

z-index: 1; to .top-nav li.menu-item ul li

The H3 of the title was covering the dropdown.